# Perl grep syntax

Tags: perl, grep

I have an HTML and TEXT Mime message.  I would like to delete the HTML part.  It looks like this will do the trick:

From [`MIME::Entity`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Entity):

```perl
### Delete some parts of a multipart message:
my @keep = grep { keep_part($_) } $msg->parts;
$msg->parts(\@keep);
```

But, I'm not sure how to read this, or really what to call it (callback?)..  I can locate the part as follows:

```perl
  for my $part ($msg->parts()) {
    if ($part->mime_type eq 'text/html') {
```

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you supply an `ARRAYREF` of `MIME::Entity`s to the `parts` function, it sets the object to contain exactly those `MIME::Entity`s. All previous entities are dropped.

The `@keep` array in the example contains those `MIME::Entity`s that for which the `keep_part` returned true and `$msg->parts(\@keep);` is what sets the new `MIME::Entity`s in `$msg`.

The implementation of `keep_part` could therefore be something like this:

```perl
sub keep_part {
    shift->mime_type ne 'text/html';
}
```

That is, it'll return true if the mime type for the supplied argument is *not* `text/html`.

If the condition isn't more complex than that, you may want to just filter it inline instead:

```perl
# create an ARRAYREF to the parts to keep and set the parts in $msg:
$msg->parts([ grep { $_->mime_type ne 'text/html' } $msg->parts]);
```

---

After the filtering has been done, you do not need to check `if ($part->mime_type eq 'text/html')` in your loop anymore. All `text/html` MIME entities will have been removed:

```perl
for my $part ($msg->parts) {
    print $part->mime_type . "\n";  # no text/html
}
```